# Multiple qrs were generated with the list, but I want to save them with the same name as the list

Tags: python, pandas, qr-code

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode

df = pd.read_excel("Manpower.xls")
df = df.drop(range(31,389))
lista = df.values.tolist()


for row in lista:
  
  qr =qrcode.QRCode(version=1,box_size=2)
  qr.add_data(row)

  qr.make(fit=True)

  img = qr.make_image()
  img.save(lista+".png")
```

The problem is when i save the img it only appear one,and doesnt save the name of the list.

Comment: All your files are being saved with the same variable where you are outputting the entire list as the filename. Do you want `img.save(row + ".png")`?

Comment: Yes i want that each row has a qr and a file.(Sorry my first time coding):C

Answer (score 0):

You are saving all your files with the same name, this is your problem. If you are okay with the name of the QR code having the name of the information in the QR code, then you could simply change the name of each file to the `row` in your loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import qrcode

df = pd.read_excel("Manpower.xls")
df = df.drop(range(31,389))
lista = df.values.tolist()


for row in lista:
  
  qr =qrcode.QRCode(version=1,box_size=2)
  qr.add_data(row)

  qr.make(fit=True)

  img = qr.make_image()
  img.save(row + ".png")
```

However, there are other options. For example, maybe want to store them as `QR1.png`, `QR2.png`, etc.
In that case you could do something like

```
#[...same as above before start of loop]
filename = "MyQRCodeFilename"
counter = 0
for row in lista:
  #[...same as above in loop]
  counter += 1 #augment counter by 1
  img.save(f"{filename}_{counter}.png")
```

Alternatively, if you wanted leading zeros you could do something like,

```
   img.save(f"{filename}_{counter:04}.png")
```

Another alternative is maybe you want a timestamp:

```
import datetime
#[...everything the same as before...]
   img.save(f"{filename}_{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')}.png")
```